# Paypal subscriptions - do not pay again (as long as the subscription is valid)

Tags: paypal, subscription

I set a button on my website. After payment, the user goes to the online game and plays. What should I do if the same user visits the site again the next day and wants to play the game again, will he need to pay again?

**How to make sure that a user who has already paid once (while his subscription is valid) does not pay again?**

if you know where to look at the solution or where to download/buy a ready-made example, I will be very grateful to you!

**I can't understand how to set it up, if the client is already my subscriber so that money will not be debited from him again? (until the subscription ends)**

Answer (score 1):

You have to find a way to keep a "connection" between your payment service provider and your application. To do that you should look for something called "[webhooks](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/webhooks/)". When someone subscribes to your application, he goes to Paypal to make the payment.

Once Paypal processes the payment, they should basically tell you that everything went right and you should give the product to that customer (in this case the subscription). Paypal does that through a webhook which is basically Paypal calling an endpoint on your website (an URL, domain.com/webhook/paypal can be a suggestive name for this). Through that endpoint, Paypal can give you any sort of information like: was the payment successful, was the payment canceled, did the user paid another month of the subscription, and so on. On your backend, you should take that information delivered by Paypal and update the subscription status for a customer inside your database.

That table, from your database, might contain information like:

- is the subscription canceled?
- is there a trial period?
  And so on.

This is a pretty complex topic. I don't really know your level of expertise but I have developed an open-source subscription-based app called [phpReel](https://github.com/phpreel/phpreel). You can check it out for more details. I will recommend using a ready-built solution for this. For phpReel I have used Laravel Cashier with Stripe (another payment processor).

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing is the need of a membership system, so that users who have paid and who have a current subscription can sign-in to that account. You will need to write your own system or look for an already developed plugin for whatever content management system (CMS) you are using -- such as wordpress, drupal, etc.

Comment: can you have an example? or how does it work that an existing subscriber does not pay the 2nd time? (while subscription is valid)

Comment: Based on your question I can only assume you want gated content, so existing subscribers will have an account to sign-in with. They won't pay again while they're subscribed, and if they are silly and try to do so you should implement some checks to prevent this.